# C++ program issue : terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::invalid_argument'

Tags: c++

I developped a code which I am trying to use to manipulate red led ( PIN 10 ) through user button ( PIN 29 ) on my SAMA5D27 embedded board.

Here is the code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include "/home/gaston/linux4sam/poky/build-microchip/tmp/sysroots-components/cortexa5hf-neon/mraa/usr/include/mraa.hpp"

#define red 10
#define USER 29

bool running = true;
bool led_state = false;
int last_touch;
void sig_handler(int signo)
{
    if (signo == SIGINT)
        running = false;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    mraa::Result ret;
    int touch;

    mraa::Gpio* touch_gpio = new mraa::Gpio(USER);
    if (touch_gpio == NULL){
        return mraa::ERROR_UNSPECIFIED;
    }
    mraa::Gpio* led_gpio = new mraa::Gpio(red);
    if (led_gpio == NULL){
        return mraa::ERROR_UNSPECIFIED;
    }

    signal(SIGINT, sig_handler);

    if ((ret = touch_gpio->dir(mraa::DIR_IN))!= mraa::SUCCESS){
        return ret;
    }
    if ((ret = led_gpio->dir(mraa::DIR_OUT))!= mraa::SUCCESS){
        return ret;
    }

    led_gpio->write(led_state);
   
    while (running) {
        touch = touch_gpio->read();
        if (touch == 1 && last_touch == 0) {
            led_state = !led_state;
            ret = led_gpio->write(led_state);
            usleep(100000);
        }
        last_touch = touch;
        usleep(1);
    }
    delete led_gpio;
    delete touch_gpio;
    return ret;
}
```

after compilation I try to execute the code but it shows me this message :

> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::invalid_argument'
>
> what():  Invalid GPIO pin specified
>
> Aborted

What's going on here and how can I fix the problem ?

Comment: So which line is throwing the exception?

Comment: *"Invalid GPIO pin specified*" - presumably one of your pin constants is wrong, double check your datasheet.

Comment: Are you running this program on your PC?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie the message which comes out did not mention a line number or anything else, I have just copied it like it is.

Comment: @Thomas Sablik no I am running it on the embedded board.

Comment: @0x5453 I am sure that I put the right pin numbers

Comment: @gaston Well, according to [this page](https://github.com/intel-iot-devkit/mraa/search?p=2&q=invalid_argument&unscoped_q=invalid_argument), that's where the error is generated.  Are you using a debugger?  At the very least, you should identify lines that are throwing exceptions.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I compile the code on my pc Linux terminal and everything goes fine without showing me errors. When I execute it on the board terminal it shows me this. I don't know how to identify the lines for you.

Comment: @gaston Well, how about `try/catch`-es to isolate the error?  You should have been doing that anyway, given that the API will throw exceptions on error.

Comment: @gaston -- If the documentation states (and it should have) that an exception is thrown on error, you're responsible in catching those exceptions and handle them accordingly.  You could isolate which line is throwing that exception by wrapping the requisite calls with `try/catch` and output your own message (maybe based on `__LINE__` or similar), giving you an idea which line caused the exception to be thrown.  But you should have been doing that already anyway (as mentioned before), since the API error reporting is based on C++ exceptions.

Answer (score -1):

Probably this line has the issue:

```
mraa::Gpio* touch_gpio = new mraa::Gpio(USER);
```

your Rasberry Pi doesn't have 29 as a pin number. Check the documentation of Rasberry Pi version. It is not the pin number but GPIO number.

Comment: It's not a raspberry pi. It's a SAMA5D27.

Comment: @azad.parinda I am using SAMA5D27-SOM1-EK1 board and I have a USER push button on GPIO 29 and RED LED on GPIO 10

Comment: what if you don't use a pointer and instead create an object of mraa?